# PHP echo a variable showing blank screen

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the following PHP code

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    $poscote = $_POST['postcode'];

    mysql_real_escape_string($poscote);

    //! Checks for direct access to page

    if (empty($_POST)) {
        header('location:index.php?nothingentered');
        die();
    }


    require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php'); 


    mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);
    $query_PC = "SELECT * FROM Postcodes WHERE pc = '$postcode'";
    $PC = mysql_query($query_PC, $Takeaway) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_PC = mysql_fetch_assoc($PC);

    if( mysql_errno() != 0){
     // mysql error
     // note: message like this should never appear to user, should be only stored in log
     echo "Mysql error: " . htmlspecialchars( mysql_error());
     die();
     }

    else {

    echo $row_PC['oc'];

    }

?>
```

This is to process a form with the following code

```
<form action="search_postcode.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="postcode" />
        <button>Go</button>
    </form>
```

Strangely its just showing a blank screen, no errors, nothing I have checked through and cannot seem to find a solution.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For blank screens, look at the [_I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?_ in the php info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

Comment: Where do you connect to your database?

Comment: @Wrikken many thanks for your comment, yes I can confirm that I have checked that page and error reporting is turned on in the script and still no joy.

Comment: @MirkoAkkov I connect to the database at  require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php'); 


    mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);

Comment: @JamesLeist: then `mysql_real_escape_string` _should_ give an error, as you _cannot use it before making a db connection_.

Comment: Also, why would you disable notices if something doesn't work?

Comment: @Wrikken No, `mysql_real_escape_string` just produces a warning and returns `false` without a database connection.

Comment: @jeroen: I didn't say it was fatal, I just said that the OP seems... lax in his providing us with error messages.

Comment: If your code is always as full of typos as this one, it's a miracle anything is showing up at all. Imagine a dentist using a sledgehammer to work your teeth. I'd not want that.

Comment: @Bart It's good to see people like you making a valid contribution to the community - thanks for your helpful feedback.

Comment: @JamesLeist: If people try to help you out by putting your literal code into a new file, only to find that they have to correct several typos first before it even remotely runs, this will frustrate them a lot. Being concise won't hurt. Especially when writing code in a language like PHP, which does not have "compile time checks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `$postcode` variable is undefined, you are looking in your database for a row where `pc` is an error message.

That query could very well finish without errors, but it probably produces 0 rows, so you don't have an error, nor do you have a result. In that case you output nothing, so you will see a blank screen.

You probably want:

```
$postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($poscote);
```

instead of:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($poscote);
```

and put it below the database connection section.

Also, you should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements to avoid sql injection problems and because the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Note that your `mysql_real_escape_string` does not do anything (except removing the contents of your variable...) when you don't have a database connection open.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, and without mentioning that you should be using `PDO` or `mysqli`, you could be having a character encoding issue. Try doing something like this:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);

...

echo "Mysql error: " .  htmlentities(mysql_error(), REPLACE_FLAGS, DB_CHARSET);
```

Replace the value of `DB_CHARSET` with whatever encoding your database is using. If you try to use `htmlentities()` with an invalid character it will produce an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As of php.net, to enable php errors using the `ini_set`, you have to do it like this

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1')
```

This is taken from this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)